# variable is null when pulling from a div

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Sorry in advance for the extremely banal question, I'm positive I am missing something extremely simple. Without further adieu;

I'm getting a type error when I try to pull a block of text, and a button, from a div in my HTML. The div has an id that I am accurately referencing. For oversight, I am attempting to retrieve the text, apply coloring to each word (cycling through red, blue, and green), and replace the original text with my colored text. It works fine in JSFiddle, but I cannot get the data to retrieve in espresso - transcribeText is null.

```
var transcribeText = document.getElementById("divideTranscript");
transcribeText.onclick = function() {

var words = document.getElementById("transcriptText");
var textArray = words.innerHTML.split(" ");
var count = 0;
var colorArr = ["red", "blue", "green"];
var newWords = document.createElement("div");

for(var i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++){
    var item = textArray[i];
    var newSpan = document.createElement("span");
    var newText = document.createTextNode(item);
    var dotNode = document.createTextNode(" ");

    newSpan.className = colorArr[count % 3];
    newSpan.id = "word"+i;

    newSpan.appendChild(newText);
    newSpan.appendChild(dotNode);
    count++;


};

words.parentNode.replaceChild(newWords, words);


}
```

---

```
   <div id="transcriptText"> It’s that time of year when you clean out your
    closets, dust off shelves, and spruce up your floors. Once you’ve taken
    care of the dust and dirt, what about some digital cleaning? Going
    through all your files and computers may seem like a daunting task, but
    we found ways to make the process fairly painless.</div>
  <br>
  <div id="divideTranscript" class="button">&nbsp;Transform the
    Transcript!&nbsp; </div>
```

Comment: transcribeText is null because the element does not exist in the DOM.

Comment: thats my button, the element does exist.

Comment: And its ID must be "transcribeText". Please post your HTML markup.

Comment: When is your code executed?  Does it wait for the document to be loaded to ensure that divideTranscript is actually in the DOM?

Comment: I updated the code to display the HTML, as well as fiddled with the button event handler. My console still tells me that the variable words is null

Comment: Add an alert into the function, just to remove the possibility of the function somehow being triggered without the user's action. And I think something is missing in your code, because you didn't add the part where you populate the `newWords` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the javascript runs before the HTML exists, therefore, you cannot get any ids. There are several ways around this. First is my favorite:

```
window.onload = function name() {
//code to be excuted
}
```

The function will be called after HTML has loaded. `body.onload = function name()` also works.

The second method (no pun intended haha) is to put the script tag at the end of the body tag.

```
<body>
<script></script>
</body>
```

Personally, I use the first one more commonly because I have a template I religiously use, and I don't like moving tags around. That's just me, whatever works for you! Hope this Helps!

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was something relatively simple, and that would explains why I could get it working in JSFiddle relatively easy, which automatically defaults to onload.

Comment: Correct, now you know. Yeah I had problems with this a while ago when i was getting the body tag as an object and it kept saying null. After research I found these solutions. Did you get the method() joke? They said to be humorous.. XD